# How to expand dataframe column of JSON string type to rows and columns

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, multiple-columns

A column inside my table contains an array JSON object (JSON string): one JSON presents a timestamp. The data is a record which the format is presented by sheet and the related data ("param_value") is a array JSON. The "param_value" contains parameters' value for each timestamp. And I want to transform it to by 'sheet', 'equipment', and 'point'. I have referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61218462/using-spark-to-expand-json-string-by-rows-and-columns) already. But I can't use '*' to select the all the schema to expand. I can't sure the schema because this work is an ETL job. And it show that I need to use structType to build the schema.

The table looks like:

| sheet | equip | param_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | E1 | [{'point':'1','status':'no','log':'no'},{'point':'2','status':'ok','log':'no'},{'point':'3', 'status':'ok','log':'ok'}] |
| a2 | E1 | [{'point':'1','status':'no','log':'no'},{'point':'2','status':'ok','log':'no'},{'point':'3', 'status':'ok','log':'ok'}] |
| a3 | E1 | [{'point':'1','status':'no','log':'no'},{'point':'2','status':'ok','log':'no'},{'point':'3', 'status':'ok','log':'ok'}] |

The expected result:

| sheet | equipment | point | status | log |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | E1 | 1 | no | no |
| a1 | E1 | 2 | ok | no |
| a1 | E1 | 3 | ok | ok |
| a2 | E1 | 1 | no | no |
| a2 | E1 | 2 | ok | no |
| a2 | E1 | 3 | ok | ok |
| a3 | E1 | 1 | no | no |
| a3 | E1 | 2 | ok | no |
| a3 | E1 | 3 | ok | ok |

Update:

As ZygD suggestion, we can define schema as a DDL-formatted string. Hence I successfully create the schema for multiple columns and no need to know each schema names. However, I need a list which contains the schema. Is there a way to `extract the schema from the array json`? ( schema in each json are the same)

```py
schema_list = ['point', 'status','log'] # -> need to extract from the array json
schema = 'array<struct<'
for c in schema_list:
    string_to_add = ',' + c +':string'
    schema = schema + string_to_add
schema = schema.replace(",", "", 1)+'>>'
s = "'" + schema + "'"
print(s)  # 'array<struct<point:string,status:string,log:string>>'
f = df.selectExpr("sheet", "equip", f"inline(from_json(param_value, {s}))")

f.show()
+-----+-----+-----+------+---+
|sheet|equip|point|status|log|
+-----+-----+-----+------+---+
|   a1|   E1|    1|    no| no|
|   a1|   E1|    2|    ok| no|
|   a1|   E1|    3|    ok| ok|
|   a2|   E1|    1|    no| no|
|   a2|   E1|    2|    ok| no|
|   a2|   E1|    3|    ok| ok|
|   a3|   E1|    1|    no| no|
|   a3|   E1|    2|    ok| no|
|   a3|   E1|    3|    ok| ok|
+-----+-----+-----+------+---+
```

Comment: What is the result of `df.printSchema()` ? I'm interested in column "param_value"

Comment: Hi ZygD, I check the schema of the table, the "param_value" datatype is string. So it is a json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract data from a JSON string you will need to use [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) for which you will need to provide the schema. If you define the schema as a DDL-formatted string, then you can use it inside [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline) which quickly extracts array of structs into columns.

Input dataframe:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a1', 'E1', "[{'point':'1','status':'no','log':'no'},{'point':'2','status':'ok','log':'no'},{'point':'3','status':'ok','log':'ok'}]"),
     ('a2', 'E1', "[{'point':'1','status':'no','log':'no'},{'point':'2','status':'ok','log':'no'},{'point':'3','status':'ok','log':'ok'}]"),
     ('a3', 'E1', "[{'point':'1','status':'no','log':'no'},{'point':'2','status':'ok','log':'no'},{'point':'3','status':'ok','log':'ok'}]")],
    ['sheet', 'equip', 'param_value'])
```

Script:

```py
schema = "array<struct<point:string,status:string,log:string>>"
df = df.selectExpr("sheet", "equip", f"inline(from_json(param_value, '{schema}'))")

df.show()
# +-----+-----+-----+------+---+
# |sheet|equip|point|status|log|
# +-----+-----+-----+------+---+
# |   a1|   E1|    1|    no| no|
# |   a1|   E1|    2|    ok| no|
# |   a1|   E1|    3|    ok| ok|
# |   a2|   E1|    1|    no| no|
# |   a2|   E1|    2|    ok| no|
# |   a2|   E1|    3|    ok| ok|
# |   a3|   E1|    1|    no| no|
# |   a3|   E1|    2|    ok| no|
# |   a3|   E1|    3|    ok| ok|
# +-----+-----+-----+------+---+
```

If you prefer not to provide schema, you can infer it, but it's less efficient:

```py
schema = f"array<{spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.param_value)).schema.simpleString()}>"
df = df.selectExpr("sheet", "equip", f"inline(from_json(param_value, '{schema}'))")

df.show()
# +-----+-----+---+-----+------+
# |sheet|equip|log|point|status|
# +-----+-----+---+-----+------+
# |   a1|   E1| no|    1|    no|
# |   a1|   E1| no|    2|    ok|
# |   a1|   E1| ok|    3|    ok|
# |   a2|   E1| no|    1|    no|
# |   a2|   E1| no|    2|    ok|
# |   a2|   E1| ok|    3|    ok|
# |   a3|   E1| no|    1|    no|
# |   a3|   E1| no|    2|    ok|
# |   a3|   E1| ok|    3|    ok|
# +-----+-----+---+-----+------+
```

Comment: Follow your suggestion, I could create a string with multiple columns for schema without knowing them. But we also need a method to get a list with columns.

Comment: @TingWeiChen - I've added an option without providing schema yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If param_value is string then you need to parse this string as a JSON and then explode it into rows and expand the keys to columns:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = [('a1', 'E1',"[{'point':'1','status':'no','log':'no'},{'point':'2','status':'ok','log':'no'},{'point':'3','status':'ok','log':'ok'}]")
       ,('a2', 'E1',"[{'point':'1','status':'no','log':'no'},{'point':'2','status':'ok','log':'no'},{'point':'3','status':'ok','log':'ok'}]")
       ,('a3', 'E1',"[{'point':'1','status':'no','log':'no'},{'point':'2','status':'ok','log':'no'},{'point':'3','status':'ok','log':'ok'}]")]

schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField('point', StringType()),
                               StructField('status', StringType()),
                               StructField('log', StringType())]))

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'equip', 'param_value'])\
    .withColumn('json_col', F.from_json(F.col('param_value'),schema))\
    .select("id", "equip", F.explode("json_col").alias("json_col"))\
    .select("id", "equip", F.col('json_col.*'))

df.show()

# +---+-----+-----+------+---+
# | id|equip|point|status|log|
# +---+-----+-----+------+---+
# | a1|   E1|    1|    no| no|
# | a1|   E1|    2|    ok| no|
# | a1|   E1|    3|    ok| ok|
# | a2|   E1|    1|    no| no|
# | a2|   E1|    2|    ok| no|
# | a2|   E1|    3|    ok| ok|
# | a3|   E1|    1|    no| no|
# | a3|   E1|    2|    ok| no|
# | a3|   E1|    3|    ok| ok|
# +---+-----+-----+------+---+
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know the shcema of json, so I need to do it like automatically expand the json.I s there any way to create the Arraytype with all schema?